# Miniflux API URL endpoint

Tags: json, api, url, endpoint

I have [Miniflux](http://miniflux.net) running on an Amazon EC2 instance which I intend to use for my Android application. According to the Miniflux documentation [here](https://miniflux.net/documentation/json-rpc-api#example-curl) I should be able to get a JSON response with this URL endpoint:

```
www.mydomain/miniflux/jsonrpc.php
```

which in my case is:

```
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":null,
  "error":{
    "code":-32700,
    "message":"Parse error"
  }
}
```

To get more information in JSON format I need to pass in more arguments but the Miniflux documentation does not explain how. The OpenWeatherMap API on the other hand, has a [guide](http://openweathermap.org/appid) on how the URL endpoint may be used with the API key. Any advice on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first go to miniflix preferences and pick your JSON-RPC URL. it must be something like: `API endpoint: https://username.miniflux.net/jsonrpc.php`.
there also you will get:

```
API username: username

API token: swB3/nSo1CB1X2F (example)
```

type the end point url into your rest client application or chrome extension like postman.
on postman use HTTP Basic Authentication. means put the your login user name in the usename field, api token in the poassword filed then click on Refresh headers button.

chose post method (as all miniflux jsonrpc calls are post) then navigate to "row" tab and write your query like:
`{"url": "http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"}, "id": 1}`

then you will see the json response.

if you want to use curl it is simple also.

```
curl \
-u "demo:swB3/nSo1CB1X2F" \
-d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "feed.create", "params": {"url": "http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"}, "id": 1}' \
https://demo.miniflux.net/jsonrpc.php
```

I suggest you to spend sometime reading their JsonRPC  code then you will come to understand all the miniflux api calls, response and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, for example, your miniflux API reports the following parameters:

```
API username: username
API endpoint: https://username.miniflux.net/jsonrpc.php
API token: swB3/nSo1CB1X2F
```

1. Lift the API method you want from direct the curl -d statements in the miniflux documentation. E.g., for the method to list all feeds (for the sake of convenience, calling it 'payload'):

   payload = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "feed.list", "id": 1}
2. Assemble a python equivalent of curl's -u command from the username and token API parameters:

   auth=('username', 'swB3/nSo1CB1X2F')
3. Import python's request and json modules and use them to query the miniflux API. The assembled request statement is equivalent to the curl command given in the miniflux documentation:

   response = requests.post('https://username.miniflux.net/jsonrpc.php', auth=auth, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()

   - using python3